# For PCM audio samples, can values like max RMS and frequency magnitude be estimated?

Tags: fft, audio, normalization, pcm, rms

I am using OpenAL and a loopback driver to grab PCM samples of whatever audio is being played on the computer in realtime. The PCM data is 1024 samples of 16 bytes (C# `short` array), and I find that data does sometimes approach the min/max values (+/-32767).

However, I am also using FFT to generate frequency magnitude values as a `double` array for bass/beat detection and such. Just experimenting, it looks like these might peak around 6000, so for visualization purposes while I program, I've been normalizing them by an arbitrarily chosen value of 6500. But they clearly aren't anywhere close to the huge values a `double` could actually store.

Similarly, I'm doing RMS calcs over a 300ms period to approximate instantaneous volume, and I have the same problem. Testing shows values peaking somewhere around 80, but I don't really know what the true range should be for normalization. There again, they're never remotely close to the mathematical maximum (sqrt of 32767^2 * 13K+ samples, which is around 3.9 million).

Is it possible to somehow calculate or estimate what the max values will be? Otherwise I'll probably try to keep some sort of sliding peak spanning a few seconds.

If it isn't already obvious, I'm a complete novice when it comes to audio, so I'm wide open to suggestions!

Comment: max and rms have definitions that are applicable to any signal.  Frequency has definition applicable to any periodic signal.